# Find max values of all subarrays of specific length

Tags: beginner, array, rust

This is one of the coding questions that I subscribe to and I wanted to solve it in Rust. I would really appreciate your feedback for improving this code and writing idiomatic Rust.

> Given an array of integers and a number k, where 1 <= k <= length of the array, compute the maximum values of each subarray of length k.
>
> For example, given `array = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7]` and `k = 3`, we should
>   get: `[10, 7, 8, 8]`, since:
>
> ```
> 10 = max(10, 5, 2)
> 7 = max(5, 2, 7)
> 8 = max(2, 7, 8)
> 8 = max(7, 8, 7)
> ```
>
> Do this in \$O(n)\$ time and \$O(k)\$ space. You can modify the input array
>   in-place and you do not need to store the results. You can simply
>   print them out as you compute them.

This is my first attempt:
https://gist.github.com/ginghamtaus/236e8a1d75237a47769ca74b23ac45ac

This is my second attempt:
https://gist.github.com/ginghamtaus/6e0003e43e020130c8fd9346c9019522

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let a = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7];
    let k = 3;
    let mut deque: VecDeque<usize> = VecDeque::new();
    for i in 0..a.len() {
        match deque.front() {
            None => deque.push_back(i),
            Some(_) => {
                let mut done = false;
                while !done {
                    match deque.back() {
                        Some(&x) => {
                            if a[i] > a[x] {
                                deque.pop_back();
                            }
                            else {
                                done = true;
                            }
                        },
                        _ => { done = true; }
                    }
                }
                deque.push_back(i); 
            }
        }

        if i + 1 >= k  {
            match deque.front() {
                Some(&x) => {
                    println!("max({:?}) = {}", &a[i+1-k..i+1], a[x]);
                    if x <= (i + 1 - k) {
                        deque.pop_front();
                    }
                },
                _ => ()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to take Ω((n-k)k) time for decreasing sequences.

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that for a small slice, the straight-forward solution `s.windows(k).filter_map(|s| s.iter().max())` is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). It will automatically tell you such things as:

   - `else` blocks in Rust belong on the same line as the closing `}` and opening `{`
   - spaces belong around binary arithmetic operators: `&a[i + 1 - k..i + 1]`.
2. Run [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy). It will automatically tell you such things as:

   - You are using `match` for a single pattern. Use `if let` instead.
3. Don't specify types of variables if type inference can handle it.
4. If you don't care about the value of an `Option`, use `is_some` / `is_none` instead of matching on it.
5. Both branches end with `push_back`, that shared logic should be pulled out of the conditional.
6. If all you care about is if the front of the queue is present, all you really care about is if it is empty.
7. You can continue to simplify by transofrming that into a `while let` and using `break`.
8. I'd create a function (or an `Iterator` implementation) to separate the algorithm and the driver.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn max_of_subarrays<F>(a: &[i32], k: usize, f: F)
where
    F: Fn(&[i32], i32),
{
    let mut deque = VecDeque::new();

    for i in 0..a.len() {
        while let Some(&x) = deque.back() {
            if a[i] > a[x] {
                deque.pop_back();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        deque.push_back(i);

        if i + 1 >= k {
            if let Some(&x) = deque.front() {
                f(&a[i + 1 - k..i + 1], a[x]);
                if x <= (i + 1 - k) {
                    deque.pop_front();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7];
    let k = 3;

    max_of_subarrays(&a, k, |sub, max| {
        println!("max({:?}) = {}", sub, max);
    });
}
```

---

Truthfully, I wouldn't do any of that unless I had a *really* good reason. Instead, I'd just use the less efficient algorithm but very concise implementation:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7];
    let k = 3;

    for (sub, max) in a.windows(k).flat_map(|sub| sub.iter().max().map(|max| (sub, max))) {
        println!("max({:?}) = {}", sub, max);
    }
}
```

I didn't take the time to benchmark this, but there's no allocation required here, so I'd expect it to be faster than the better algorithm in certain cases.